# Can I use CSS Flexbox to remove columns?

Tags: css, flexbox, footable

Is there some way CSS flexbox will remove columns (flex items) when the available real estate is small - similar to the functionality provided by FooTable?

Answer (score 2):

The element will tighten up to `0px` if needed. Hiding the content can be handled by using `overflow: hidden`, *but* beware that this may create problems in other scenarios.
Check the following snippet to see the result:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.child1, .child3 {
    flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.child2 {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">child1</div>
    <div class="child2">child2</div>
    <div class="child3">child3</div>
</div>
```

Other suggestions:

- Use media queries to hide the content depending on the window size;
- Use media queries to apply the `overflow` property depending on the window size;
- If you don't want to hide it, go with `flex-wrap` to spread your flex items into 2+ rows

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but I was hoping to find a solution where child2 is visible sometimes (big container), and not visible at other times (smaller container).

Comment: thank you for sticking with this, but I never see child2.  Even when I click the Full page button, child2 is always hidden.  I am using Chrome.

Comment: @Upperstage right, because the other elements are occupying the rest of the container. If you give enough room for `.child2` to be shown, it'll be shown. If you need some more specific control over this flex item, you should go with JS or media queries.

Comment: "If you give enough room for .child2 to be shown, it'll be shown" - sorry, but I tried Chrome and Firefox (doesn't work in IE), but I never see child2.

Comment: Yes, because the other flex items have 50% width :)

Comment: That misses the point of my question.  I want to SEE child2 when real estate is available.